# Tweaking smplayer for quality over performance

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, video, mplayer

Hi I don't know a lot about video players or codecs and that sort of thing, and I am trying to squeeze the best possible quality picture out of Mplayer (I am using the SMplayer front end).

My questions are should I enable post prossesing (I dont know what this is but it looks like it might improve quality) and direct rendering ? (also sounds like it could increase quality) can any one explain what these do ?.

As for output driver I use vdpau is this best for nvidia cards ?

Any other suggestions welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91774/is-mplayer-multi-threaded), which suggests multi-threading: `-lavdopts threads=2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `vdpau` with Nvidia cards should get you great performance with `smplayer`, and will ensure that you use very little cpu when playing dvds and x264 encoded video. As has been discussed in detail on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1037625&page=2), it is very **important** to note that

> Vdpau is two things. One, a display device, like xv. The other, a codec that can use the PureVideo chip to decode certain files

such as mpeg1/2 and x264. If your card supports it (see [here for a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_PureVideo) of supported gpus) it is a better option than the old `xv`, and particularly `xll`, which will use considerably more cpu.

In `smplayer` there are some options that can be accessed via the configure button next to the `vdpau` option (see screenshot), but you usually don't have to fiddle with these unless you have any problems with the video performance.

NOTE: It is **particularly important** to note that when `vdpau` codecs such as `ffh264vdpau` are being utilised, **none** of the following `smplayer` gui options such as `post-processing`, `deinterlace`, etc, will have any effect. In the screenshot you can also see that 'disable software video filters' is checked when you click the `vdpau` properties.

However, as noted in the [Mplayer manual](http://www.mplayer2.org/docs/mplayer/) special options such as `deint` can be passed on the command-line when using vdpau, although these are not usually needed; these special options are not supported in the `smplayer` gui.

```
vdpau (with -vc ffmpeg12vdpau, ffwmv3vdpau, ffvc1vdpau, ffh264vdpau  or
       ffodivxvdpau)
       Video output that uses VDPAU to decode video via hardware.  Also
              supports displaying of software-decoded video.
       sharpen=<-1-1>
                      For positive values, apply a sharpening algorithm to the
                      video, for negative values  a  blurring  algorithm  (de-
                      fault: 0).
       denoise=<0-1>
                      Apply a noise reduction algorithm to the video (default:
                      0, no noise reduction).
       deint=<0-4>
                      Select the deinterlacer (default: 0).  All modes > 0 re-
                      spect -field-dominance.
```

As has been shown at [this forum discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=102992),

```
deint is a option for the video out (vdpau) not for the codec
```

and so to specify one of these special options  (where `vo` is video output and  `vc` is video codec), you could use the following command (taken from the forum above):

```
mplayer -vo vdpau:deint=1 -vc ffh264vdpau 00007.MTS
```

So, when using `vdpau` you **don't** really need to worry about these special options or any other settings in the `smplayer` gui such as `post-processing` or `direct rendering` that you can't normally apply anyway when using `vdpau`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to contribute to Mik's answer, you can use vdpau in smplayer and turn on deinterlacing by adding the command line arguments in the SMPlayer preferences menu.

Preferences > Advanced > Options for MPlayer

In the Options box, add the command line arguments you want. e.g.

```
-vo vdpau:deint=1
```